# Android default media player access

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

I'm coding an app that works with the current status of the Android Media Player, basically, I'm trying to find a way to obtain, for example, the current track information or the track next on the library/playlist.

Thing is, I couldn't find any way to "connect" to the app, I read about some services and copying an Android MP file to my project and so on, but I just wanted to check if there's another way such as a content provider.

Comment: http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commonsware mentioned, there is no official method for accessing the Music Player status. There is an unofficial method though..

**WARNING: This is an unofficial method and will probably break in the future. So, don't use it for any production applications.**
The unofficial method of accessing `IMediaPlaybackService` is described in [this blog post by Alex Curelea](http://www.alexc.me/android-music-app-service-currently-playing-song/231/) and there is sample code in the [scrobbledroid Google Code Project](http://code.google.com/p/scrobbledroid).

Answer (score 2):

The Music application is [not part of the SDK](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/14/code-pollution-reaching-past-the-sdk/), so there is no reliable and supported way to interact with it.